# How to access other function in UI5 custom control/type?

Tags: sapui5

I defined many custom type in Utils.js: http://plnkr.co/edit/BGqDoWEC7DTmomEFHygd?p=catalogue

I want to add `trim()` in `parseValue`

```
parseValue: function (oValue) {
    if(oValue !== null) {
        return oValue.trim();
    }
    return oValue;
},
```

Copy and paste this function is kind of dumb, so I want to do sth. like :

```
trimString : function(oValue) {
    if(oValue !== null) {
        return oValue.trim();
    }
    return oValue;
},

mandatoryValueType : SimpleType.extend("text", {
    formatValue: function (oValue) {
        return oValue;
    },
    parseValue: this.trimString,
    validateValue: function (oValue) {
        if (!oValue) {
            throw new ValidateException(Utils.i18n("MANDATORY_VALIDATE_ERROR"));
        }  
    }
}),
```

But scope in `mandatoryValueType` seems can not access to `this.trimString`, what can I do?

`this` scope in `parseValue` function, no `trimString` function: 
[image]

Another working sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/ahS6NlUHHL0kdvdddvgd?p=preview
Reference: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview

Comment: Anyone down vote this answer please kindly leave a reason, happy to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can put the `trimString` function outside the `var Utils` object, and set it as a global function.

here is the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/u64DEP0RnT5CJADZyXJg?p=catalogue

**edit:**

corrected by @boghyon, the `trimString` function should be a function in a closure, instead of a global function :)

Comment: In this case, `trimString` is not a *global* function. It's a function in a *closure*.. Sorry, I had to say that :P

Answer (score 0):

in this case the `this` keyword contains the object which invokes the function: the `controller` which invokes `mandatoryValueType` of `utils.js`.

initialise in `utils.js` in the upper scope of `mandatoryValueType` a `var that = this`. then use inside of `mandatoryValueType` instead of `this.trimString` the `that.trimString`.

**edit**

[self reference to a property of an object in a literal declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations) of an object:

```
var Utils = {
  ...
  trimString: function() {
    ...
  },
  ...
  parseValue: function() {
    this.trimString();
  }
  ..
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yGZxBHsW3FC1u6Pit31I?p=catalogue Added `that` in Utils.js, but still not working...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pWqOq60broDI8GovEwQ1?p=preview make a demo in controller.js, but after change `email` input, there will be an error: `this.oType.parseValue is not a function`

Comment: i guess i misunderstood your question. anyway, please try in the plnkr code sample of the first comment `parseValue: function() {this.trimString}` instead of `parseValue: this.trimString`. or in es6 'get parseValue() {this.trimString}'.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pWqOq60broDI8GovEwQ1?p=preview Updated. `that` scope is `window`... `that.trimString` returned `undefined`.

Comment: so, is parseValue inside a controller as a method or inside the util object of another module as the controller from which parseValue gets invoked?

Comment: Inside `Utils.js`, I used it in controller just for simple demo.

Comment: This type is use in Master.view.xml. In Master.controller.js, I sap.ui.defined `namespace/util/Utils`, and before `onInit` I add `Utils : Utils`

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: `this` has changed since `parseValue` is in `SimpleType.extend`, please refer to my update in question. Thanks